# Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: where near line

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

```
      Root<Purchases> purchasesRoot = cq.from(Purchases.class);
       Root<TaskProcesses> taskProcessesRoot = cq.from(TaskProcesses.class);
       //task
       Subquery<Tasks> tasksSubquery = cq.subquery(Tasks.class);
       // task process
       Subquery<TaskProcesses> taskProcessesSubquery = cq.subquery(TaskProcesses.class);
       //Join<Tasks,TaskProcesses> tasksTaskProcessesJoin = tasksRoot.join("taskProcesses",JoinType.LEFT);
       //Join<Tasks,Purchases> purchasesTasksJoin = tasksRoot.join("tasks",JoinType.LEFT);
       taskProcessesSubquery.select(taskProcessesRoot);
       taskProcessesSubquery = taskProcessesSubquery.where(cb.and(
               cb.equal(tasksRoot.get("id"),taskProcessesRoot.get("taskId")),
               cb.in(taskProcessesRoot.get("orgId")).value(this.getOrgIds()),
               cb.equal(taskProcessesRoot.get("type"),"purchase"),
               cb.equal(taskProcessesRoot.get("status"),intStatusNum)
       ));
       tasksSubquery.select(tasksRoot);
       tasksSubquery = tasksSubquery.where(cb.and(
               cb.equal(root.get("id"),tasksRoot.get("missionId")),
               cb.equal(tasksRoot.get("missionType"),"purchase"),
               cb.exists(taskProcessesSubquery)

       ));
       predicate.add(cb.and(
               cb.exists(tasksSubquery),
               cb.equal(root.get("status"),intStatusNum)
       ));
```

My Error is given below:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: where near line 1, column 317 [select generatedAlias0 from com.runoclound.warehouse.model.Purchases as generatedAlias0, com.runoclound.warehouse.model.Tasks as generatedAlias1, com.runoclound.warehouse.model.Purchases as generatedAlias2, com.runoclound.warehouse.model.TaskProcesses as generatedAlias3 where ( exists (select generatedAlias1 from  where ( generatedAlias0.id=generatedAlias1.missionId ) and ( generatedAlias1.missionType=:param0 ) and ( exists (select generatedAlias3 from  where ( generatedAlias1.id=generatedAlias3.taskId ) and ( generatedAlias3.orgId in (:param1) ) and ( generatedAlias3.type=:param2 ) and ( generatedAlias3.status=0 )) )) ) and ( generatedAlias0.status=0 ) order by generatedAlias0.createdAt desc]
```

Comment: I want to write like this ```SELECT *
FROM `purchases`
WHERE ((`status` = ?))
 AND EXISTS (
 SELECT *
 FROM `tasks`
 WHERE `purchases`.`id` = `tasks`.`mission_id` AND `tasks`.`mission_type` = ? 
  AND EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM `task_processes`
  WHERE `tasks`.`id` = `task_processes`.`task_id` AND `org_id` in (?) AND (`type` = ?) AND (`status` = ?)
  )
 AND `tasks`.`deleted_at` IS NULL
)
 AND `purchases`.`deleted_at` IS NULL
ORDER BY `updated_at` DESC how to write?```

Comment: ```cb.in(taskProcessesRoot.get("orgId")).value(this.getOrgIds())``` u have to sure ```this.getOrgIds()``` is not empty

Comment: yes , this is not empty .i am sure!

Comment: Just a question that has nothing to do with your question :Why don't you use Metadata API?

Comment: You have commented tasksRoot. Why?

Comment: i know the reason that subquery is missed from the SQL, but I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: I dont want to use JOIN, I would like to use "=" to join.....

Comment: I have solved it！！haha